# Find queries and source table names behind OLAP/Tabular cubes

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, olap-cube, ssas-tabular

Is there a way to retrieve the queries and/or the original table names attached to the tables of an SSAS cube (OLAP or Tabular) using DMVs or others?

Answer (score 0):

Could you import the definition of the cube into visual studio by pointing at the cube on the server?

Comment: Yes I can. In case of new added features in the SSAS solution, I would like to automate the extraction of the metadata in an SQL table (in particular, the source data query).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use [Tabular Editor](https://github.com/otykier/tabulareditor). Open your model directly from the database, then paste the following script into the "Advanced Scripting" tab and hit F5:

```cs
ExportProperties(Model.AllPartitions, "Name,Table,Query").Output();
```

This will output the name, parent table and query of all partitions in your model. If you hit "Copy to clipboard" on the window that pops up, you can paste the result into Excel, and it'll look as follows:

[image]

More examples on how to document your model with Tabular Editor here: https://github.com/otykier/TabularEditor/wiki/Useful-script-snippets#export-object-properties-to-a-file

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to the cube in Visual Studio.
2. Double click your cube in Solution Explorer
3. On the left pane you will see Dimensions - right click and Edit Dimension
4. You will see on the right window called Data Source View with tables - click on the table and in the properties window you will see Query Definition in SQL